# How to arrive at this solution to an integral over the Bessel function of the first kind?

Tags: integration, complex-numbers, bessel-functions, analytic-functions

I am trying to solve a complex integral over $y$, and am really struggling so would appreciate some help. The function is given by
$$
f(x) = \frac{2a}{i}e^{iax^2}\int_0^\infty p(y)\; e^{iay^2} J_0(2axy)\;y\;\; \textrm{d}y, \tag{1}
$$
where $p(y) = \textrm{circ}(y/R)$ is the [circ function](http://www.optique-ingenieur.org/en/courses/OPI_ang_M02_C01/co/Contenu_04.html), $J_0$ is the zero-order Bessel function of the first kind, and $a$ and $R$ are positive, real constants.

In Eq. (2) of [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0030402605001221?casa_token=7N2MJNY8_z0AAAAA:N-wJIfCpvwvm9pNvd9fkDxdDM_l9WO3u7UzCx-MKqX4vxpgIIyN7dFSmi8bB48KKMhArsm87nw), it is simply stated that the solution is written as
$$
f(x) = 1-e^{iax^2}e^{iaR^2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \bigg( -i\frac{x}{R} \bigg)^n J_n(2aRx), \tag{2}
$$
and that this was arrived at using partial integration together with the differential formula for Bessel functions
$$
\frac{\textrm{d}}{\textrm{d}z}z^{n+1}J_{n+1}(z)=z^{n+1}J_n(z).\tag{3}
$$

I cannot figure out how to attack this problem, and how to obtain Eq. (2) from Eq. (1). If someone is able to see it I would appreciate being walked through the steps. Thank you!

Comment: By circular function do you mean sine, cosine, etc?

Comment: @K.defaoite Sorry, I mean a function such that if $y>R$ then $p=0$, and if $y<R$ then $p=1$.

Comment: Then we can change the range of integration from $0$ to $R$, no?

Comment: Yes we can, but I wasn't sure if leaving the upper limit as $\infty$ actually meant that the integral reduced to a standard one, or simplified somehow, so I left it there just in case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By changing $z=2axy$, an expression for the function is
\begin{align}
f(x)& = \frac{2a}{i}e^{iax^2}\int_0^R e^{iay^2} J_0(2axy)y\,{d}y\\
&= \frac{e^{iax^2}}{2iax^2}\int_0^{2axR} e^{i\frac{z^2}{4ax^2}} J_0(z)z\,{d}z
\end{align}
With $X=2axR,\lambda=i/(4ax^2)$ and
\begin{equation}
K=\int_0^Xe^{\lambda z^2}z J_0(z)\,dz
\end{equation}
we have to evaluate
\begin{equation}
f(x)=e^{iax^2} (-2\lambda) K
\end{equation}
From the quoted property (3), $zJ_0(z)=d/dz\left( zJ_1(z) \right)$, integrating by parts gives
\begin{align}
K&= \left.zJ_1(z)e^{\lambda z^2}\right|_0^X-2\lambda \int_0^Xe^{\lambda z^2}z^2 J_1(z)\,dz\\
&=XJ_1(X)e^{\lambda X^2}-2\lambda \int_0^Xe^{\lambda z^2}z^2 J_1(z)\,dz
\end{align}
Now, using again the differentiation property, integration by parts of this new integral gives
\begin{equation}
\int_0^Xe^{\lambda z^2}z^2 J_1(z)\,dz=X^2J_2(X)e^{\lambda X^2}-2\lambda \int_0^Xe^{\lambda z^2}z^3 J_2(z)\,dz
\end{equation}
By induction, admitting that the series converges,
\begin{equation}
K=e^{\lambda X^2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-2\lambda )^{k-1}X^kJ_k(X)
\end{equation}
Then,
\begin{align}
f(x)&=e^{iax^2+iaR^2} \sum_{k=1}^\infty(-2\lambda X )^{k}J_k(X)\\
&=e^{iax^2+iaR^2} \sum_{k=1}^\infty(-\frac{iR}{x})^{k}J_k(2axR)
\end{align}
The [generating function for the Bessel functions](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.12.E1)
$$e^{\frac{1}{2}z(t-t^{-1})}=\sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}t^{m}J_{m}\left(z\right)$$
gives the expressions
\begin{align}
 \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty(-\frac{iR}{x})^{k}J_k(2axR)&=J_0(2axR)+\left( \sum_{k=-\infty}^{-1}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \right)(-\frac{iR}{x})^{k}J_k(2axR)\\
 &=e^{-ia\left( x^2+R^2 \right)}
\end{align}
from which, we deduce
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-\frac{iR}{x})^{k}J_k(2axR)=e^{-ia\left( x^2+R^2 \right)}-J_0(2axR)-\sum_{k=-\infty}^{-1}(-\frac{iR}{x})^{k}J_k(2axR)
\end{equation}
As $J_{-n}(z)=(-1)^nJ_n(x)$ and including the term $J_0(2axR)$ in the series, we have
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-\frac{iR}{x})^{k}J_k(2axR)=e^{-ia\left( x^2+R^2 \right)}-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-\frac{ix}{R})^{k}J_k(2axR)
\end{equation}
Finally,
\begin{equation}
f(x)=1-e^{ia\left( x^2+R^2 \right)}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-\frac{ix}{R})^{k}J_k(2axR)
\end{equation}
as expected.

Comment: Fantastic - thanks for taking your time to write the answer. Please be patient with me whilst I go through it. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. The term $J_0(2axR)$ was forgotten. This is corrected now.

Answer (score 2):

As it is mentioned, it is just partial integration. So start with
$$\int_0^\infty p(y)\; e^{iay^2} J_0(2axy) \,y \,  {\rm d}y = \int_0^R e^{iay^2} J_0(2axy) \,y \,  {\rm d}y \\ \stackrel{z=2axy}{=} \frac{1}{(2ax)^2} \int_0^{2axR} z \, e^{\frac{iaz^2}{(2ax)^2}} \, J_0(z) \, {\rm d}z=\frac{1}{2ia}\int_0^{2axR} \left( \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}z} \, e^{\frac{iaz^2}{(2ax)^2}} \right) J_0(z) \, {\rm d}z \\
= \frac{e^{\frac{iaz^2}{(2ax)^2}}}{2ia} \, J_0(z)\bigg|_0^{2axR} - \frac{1}{2ia} \int_0^{2axR} z\, e^{\frac{iaz^2}{(2ax)^2}} z^{-1}J_{-1}(z) \, {\rm d}z \\
= \frac{e^{iaR^2}}{2ia} \, J_0(2axR) - \frac{1}{2ia} - e^{\frac{iaz^2}{(2ax)^2}}  \frac{(2ax)^2}{(2ia)^2} \, z^{-1} J_{-1}(z) \bigg|_0^{2axR} \\+ \frac{(2ax)^2}{(2ia)^2} \int_0^{2axR} z \, e^{\frac{iaz^2}{(2ax)^2}} z^{-2}J_{-2}(z) \, {\rm d}z \\
= -\frac{1}{2ia}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{(2ax)^{2k}}{(2ia)^k} \, \frac{2^{-k}}{k!} + \frac{e^{iaR^2}}{2ia} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left(i\,\frac{x}{R}\right)^k \, J_{-k}(2axR) \\
+ (-1)^n \frac{(2ax)^{2n-2}}{(2ia)^n} \int_0^{2axR} z\, e^{\frac{iaz^2}{(2ax)^2}} z^{-n}J_{-n}(z) \, {\rm d}z$$
which you can prove by induction and the formulas $$\lim_{z\rightarrow 0} \frac{J_n(z)}{z^n} = \frac{2^{-n}}{n!} \\
J_{-n}(z)=(-1)^n J_n(z) \\
\frac{\textrm{d}}{\textrm{d}z}z^{-n}J_{-n}(z)=z^{-n}J_{-n-1}(z) \, .$$

Estimating the remainder integral using $$|J_n(z)|\leq \frac{2^{-n}z^n}{n!}$$ shows that it vanishes in the limit $n\rightarrow \infty$. Hence $${-2ia} \, e^{iax^2} \int_0^\infty p(y)\; e^{iay^2} J_0(2axy) \,y \,  {\rm d}y \\
=-2ia \, e^{iax^2} \left( -\frac{1}{2ia}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-iax^2)^k}{k!} + \frac{e^{iaR^2}}{2ia} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(-i\,\frac{x}{R}\right)^k \, J_{k}(2axR) \right) \\
=1-e^{ia(R^2+x^2)} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(-i\,\frac{x}{R}\right)^k \, J_{k}(2axR)  \tag{1}$$

and we are done.

---

**Addon:**

Similarly we can integrate by parts the other way around
$$\int_0^\infty p(y)\; e^{iay^2} J_0(2axy) \,y \,  {\rm d}y = \int_0^R e^{iay^2} J_0(2axy) \,y \,  {\rm d}y \stackrel{z=2axy}{=} \frac{1}{(2ax)^2} \int_0^{2axR} e^{\frac{iaz^2}{(2ax)^2}} zJ_0(z) \, {\rm d}z \\
=\frac{1}{(2ax)^2} \, e^{\frac{iaz^2}{(2ax)^2}} \, zJ_1(z) \bigg|_0^{2ax R} - \frac{2ia}{(2ax)^4} \int_0^{2axR} e^{\frac{iaz^2}{(2ax)^2}} z^2 J_1(z) \, {\rm d}z\\
=\frac{R}{2ax} \, e^{iaR^2} \, J_1(2axR) - \frac{2ia \, R^2}{(2ax)^2} \, e^{iaR^2} \, J_2(2axR) + \frac{(2ia)^2}{(2ax)^6} \int_0^{2axR} e^{\frac{iaz^2}{(2ax)^2}} z^3 J_2(z) \, {\rm d}z = \dots$$
and so on. Therefore we can guess $$=e^{iaR^2} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-2ia)^{k}\left( \frac{R}{2ax} \right)^{k+1} J_{k+1}(2axR) + \frac{(-2ia)^n}{(2ax)^{2n+2}} \int_0^{2axR} e^{\frac{iaz^2}{(2ax)^2}} z^{n+1} J_{n}(z) \, {\rm d}z$$
which can be proved again by induction. The case $n=1$ is evident. Suppose it is true for $n$, then for $n\rightarrow n+1$ we have $$e^{iaR^2} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-2ia)^{k}\left( \frac{R}{2ax} \right)^{k+1} J_{k+1}(2axR) \\ 
+ e^{iaR^2} (-2ia)^n \, \left(\frac{R}{2ax} \right)^{n+1} \, J_{n+1}(2axR)  + \frac{(-2ia)^{n+1}}{(2ax)^{2n+4}} \int_0^{2axR} e^{\frac{iaz^2}{(2ax)^2}} z^{n+2} J_{n+1}(z) \, {\rm d}z \\
=e^{iaR^2} \sum_{k=0}^{n} (-2ia)^{k}\left( \frac{R}{2ax} \right)^{k+1} J_{k+1}(2axR) + \frac{(-2ia)^{n+1}}{(2ax)^{2n+4}} \int_0^{2axR} e^{\frac{iaz^2}{(2ax)^2}} z^{n+2} J_{n+1}(z) \, {\rm d}z$$
which is what we needed to show.

Now we estimate the remainder term and substitute $z=2axRu$ s.t. $$\left|\frac{(-2ia)^{n}}{(2ax)^{2n+2}} \int_0^{2axR} e^{\frac{iaz^2}{(2ax)^2}} z^{n+1} J_{n}(z) \, {\rm d}z\right|\leq R^2 \left(\frac{R}{x}\right)^n \int_0^1 u^{n+1} |J_n(2axRu)| \, {\rm d}u \leq R^2 \left(\frac{R}{x}\right)^n $$
since $|J_n|\leq 1$. Now if $x>R$ this vanishes exponentially as $n\rightarrow\infty$ giving $${-2ia} \, e^{iax^2} \int_0^\infty p(y)\; e^{iay^2} J_0(2axy) \,y \,  {\rm d}y \\= e^{ia(x^2+R^2)} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left( -i\,\frac{R}{x} \right)^{k} J_{k}(2axR) = e^{ia(x^2+R^2)} \sum_{k=-\infty}^{-1} \left( -i\,\frac{x}{R} \right)^{k} J_{k}(2axR) \tag{2}$$
since $J_{-k}(x)=(-1)^kJ_k(x)$.

By combining the previous two results (1)=(2), you'll get the Laurent expansion $$\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \left(-i\,\frac{x}{R}\right)^k \, J_{k}(2axR)=e^{-ia(R^2+x^2)} $$
i.e. the generating function for the Bessel-functions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer - I am working through it, along with the answer above. Thanks!